# Error connecting cloud database executing OLAP JOB

Tags: ssms, olap-cube, dts

I've created some OLAP Cubes and a DTSX Package. In this package I connect into a cloud database to get my data and put in on local SQL analysis service.

On Visual Studio when I execute it it works fine, but when I try to run it on a local SQL environment in SQL Server Management Studio with a job, it gives me errors on cloud database credentials.

> Description: Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password" with error 0x8009000B "Key not valid for use in specified state.". You may not be authorized to access this information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic error. Verify that the correct key is available.

I tried to change Protection level and to wait for validation, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by manually adding the password in the dtsx package into the connection string for cloud. The package itself didn't save the sensitive data provided in the connection manager.